# What is the equivalent of "restore system" on mac?

Tags: macos, mac

In windows there is an option "create restore point", which is quite useful in case when something breaks or fails in the system, we can go back to a specific date in the whole computer. Is there a similar option on mac?

thanks

Comment: Time Machine. Mac has no restore points.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a similar option on mac?

You can use Time Machine:

> Unfortunately, Mac does not provide a system restore option like its
>   Windows counterpart. However, if you are using Mac OS X as well as an
>   external drive or AirPort Time Capsule, a built-in back up feature
>   called Time Machine may help you achieve your ends. Time Machine
>   automatically backs up every aspect of your computer's hard drive at
>   several points in time. It also allows you the option of restoring
>   your Mac to one of these points through OS X Recovery.
>
> **OS X Recovery**
>
> Press both the "Command" key and the letter "R" at the same time to
>   enter OS X Recovery. Hold these buttons down until you see the Apple
>   logo. A recovery menu will display that includes the option to restore
>   your computer from a Time Machine backup. Choose this option and
>   choose the point in time to which you want your computer to go back.

Source [Apple Support: How to System Restore to a Previous Time | Chron.com](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/apple-support-system-restore-previous-time-79881.html)

---

#### How do I create a Time Machine backup??

> You can use Time Machine, the built-in backup feature of your Mac, to
>   automatically back up all your files, including apps, music, photos,
>   email, documents and system files. When you have a backup, you can
>   restore files from your backup if the original files are ever deleted
>   from your Mac or the hard disk (or SSD) in your Mac is erased or
>   replaced.
>
> **Create a Time Machine backup**
>
> To create backups with Time Machine, all you need is an external
>   storage device. After you connect the device and select it as your
>   backup disk, Time Machine automatically makes hourly backups for the
>   past 24 hours, daily backups for the past month and weekly backups for
>   all previous months. The oldest backups are deleted when your backup
>   disk is full.
>
> **Connect an external storage device**
>
> Connect one of the following external storage devices, sold
>   separately. Learn more about backup disks that you can use with Time
>   Machine.
>
> - External drive connected to your Mac, such as a USB, Thunderbolt or FireWire drive
> - External drive connected to an AirPort Extreme Base Station (802.11ac model) or AirPort Time Capsule
> - AirPort Time Capsule
> - Mac shared as a Time Machine backup destination
> - Network-attached storage (NAS) device that supports Time Machine over SMB
>
> Select your storage device as the backup disk
>
> When you connect an external drive directly to your Mac, you might be
>   asked if you want to use the drive to back up with Time Machine.
>   Select Encrypt Backup Disk (recommended), then click Use as Backup
>   Disk.
>
> An encrypted backup is accessible only to users with the password.
>   Learn more about keeping your backup disk secure.

Source [Back up your Mac with Time Machine – Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201250)